# jQuery access JSON Object

Tags: jquery, json

How do I access the name of an item in an Object Literal using jQuery?

For example how would I read "title", "link", "media", ect... in this

```
{
    "title": "What we do in our free time...",
    "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/tnhimmies/4042938515/",
    "media": {"m":"http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2572/4042938515_3a00561320_m.jpg"},
    "date_taken": "2009-10-24T03:48:10-08:00",
    "description": "<p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/people/tnhimmies/\">Darlene, TN Persians (www.tnpurrs.com)<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/photos/tnhimmies/4042938515/\" title=\"What we do in our free time...\"><img src=\"http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2572/4042938515_3a00561320_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"230\" alt=\"What we do in our free time...\" /><\/a><\/p> <p>Tennessee Persians<br /> <a href=\"http://www.tnpurrs.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">www.tnpurrs.com<\/a><\/p>",
    "published": "2009-10-25T18:28:36Z",
    "author": "nobody@flickr.com (Darlene, TN Persians (www.tnpurrs.com))",
    "author_id": "66405213@N00",
    "tags": "cat persian tnpurrs"
},
```

Comment: BTW, it isn't an *associative array* is an *Object Literal* http://is.gd/4BdvZ

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can also use the [$.each](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each) function:

```
var obj = { one:1, two:2, three:3, four:4, five:5 };

$.each(obj, function(key, value) {
  //..
});
```

If you go for the [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/for...in) statement way, I would recommend you to check if the property resides directly on the object being iterated, because you could have [some](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/09/26/for-in-intrigue/) [issues](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#forin), if the Object.prototype is extended:

```
for(var key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    // value = obj[key];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
for (var key in json) {
  // ...
}
```

(this is standard javascript, not jQuery-speficic)

Comment: This is correct but just like @CMS mentioned in his answer, always check if key is a property of json and not property of prototype, otherwise you can run into issues. Simply check `if (json.hasOwnProperty(key) { //do stuff};`.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, this is not an array at all! You want to loop through properties of an object.

JavaScript does not truly support associative arays either... see http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays

Zed's answer is perfect, I would add

```
alert(json[key]);
```

inside the for, if you wonder how to get the value of the propery

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var testObject = {
    "title": "What we do in our free time...",
    "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/tnhimmies/4042938515/",
    "media": {"m":"http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2572/4042938515_3a00561320_m.jpg"},
    "date_taken": "2009-10-24T03:48:10-08:00",
    "description": "<p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/people/tnhimmies/\">Darlene, TN Persians (www.tnpurrs.com)<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/photos/tnhimmies/4042938515/\" title=\"What we do in our free time...\"><img src=\"http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2572/4042938515_3a00561320_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"230\" alt=\"What we do in our free time...\" /><\/a><\/p> <p>Tennessee Persians<br /> <a href=\"http://www.tnpurrs.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">www.tnpurrs.com<\/a><\/p>",
    "published": "2009-10-25T18:28:36Z",
    "author": "nobody@flickr.com (Darlene, TN Persians (www.tnpurrs.com))",
    "author_id": "66405213@N00",
    "tags": "cat persian tnpurrs"
};
```

if it is single object then you can access this by
  testObject.tags or testObject.title ... like this

or you can iterate by

```
$.each(obj,function(key,value){
///
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access without each loop if you wanted.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
var title  = obj[0].title;
```