# jQuery templates - Rendering out generic json object

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I'm trying to create a generic template which will render out JSON objects. The problem is, with all the samples I have seen, they are based on knowing the names of the key...

I started off trying something like this:

```
<table>
    {{each}}
    <tr>
        <td>$($value[0]}</td><td>$($value[1]}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
```

Now I this isn't generic yet but I was trying this as a start, but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was not apparent to me either.

```
<table>
     <tr>
        {{each $data}}
        <td>${ $index }</td><td>${ $value }</td>
        {{/each}}
     </tr>
</table>
```

But when you see it you have a D'OH moment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that will get you the keys and values of your JSON object.  I'm basing this off of [jQuery JSON Associative Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621685/jquery-json-associative-array).

```
for(var key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    document.write("<tr><td>" + key + "</td><td>" + obj[key] + "</td></tr>");
  }
}
```

It's standard javascript.  There's an shorter way to do this in jQuery (mentioned in the previous link).

Comment: I know i could do this, but the idea is that its supposed to be using a template as there are other factors at work here...